# accurate stopwatch by embedded C

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I would like to make a stopwatch by embedded C to program on ST STM32F407VG.
I know how I should write a clock program to make a hundredth of sec,but I know it will not be accurate,when I use a delay of 10ms. 
what should I do

Comment: 'Up to 17 timers: up to twelve 16-bit and two 32-bit timers up to 168 MHz, each with up to 4 IC/OC/PWM or pulse counter and quadrature (incremental) encoder input '   I'm sure you can manage better than 10ms....

Comment: Why do you "know" it will not be accurate?  It depends entirely on how you implement the delay.  The device has hardware timers that will be as accurate as your clock source.

Answer (score 5):

While the STM32 is endowed with a number of hardware timers, *all* Cortex-M devices have a common SYSTICK timer, so the simplest and most portable method is to use that.

The following creates a 1 millisecond period free-running counter `msTicks`:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include <stdint.h>

static volatile uint32_t msTicks = 0; // Milliseconds

int main(void)  
{
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000) ;  // 1ms interrupt

    for(;;)
    {
        ...  // your code here
    }
}

// SYSTICK interrupt handler
void SysTick_Handler(void)  
{
    msTicks++ ;
}
```

Then your stopwatch can be implemented with two functions thus:

```
static uint32_t start_time ;
void start( void )
{
    start_time = msTicks ;
}

uint32_t getMillisecondsSinceStart( void )
{
    return msTicks - start_time ;
}
```

For example:

```
bool running = false ; // needs <stdbool.h> included
uint32_t time_millisec = 0 ;

for(;;)
{
    if( startButtonPressed() )
    {
        running = true ;
        start() ;
    }

    if( stopButtonPressed() )
    {
        running = false ;
    }

    if( running )
    {
        time_millisec = getMillisecondsSinceStart() ;
    }

    displayTime( time_millisec ) ;
}
```

Accuracy will be entirely dependent on whatever is driving the core clock - normally an external crystal or oscillator.  The internal RC oscillator will be less precise - it is factory trimmed to +/- 1%.  Your particular part also has a 32KHz RC oscillator for driving the RTC that can be calibrated, but that cannot be used to drive the core clock (systick), and would be less portable, less precise and more complex that the method described above.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the internal timer modules of that microcontroller. About which you can explore in the datasheet.